# Changing capitalization with for loops and list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a assignment where I need to

> sometimes it might be useful to convert text from lowerCamelCase to snake_case. The main trick is to find the correct place where to insert an underscore. Let's make a rule that it's right before a capital letter of the next word. If the first letter is capitalized, convert it to lowercase and don't forget to insert an underscore before it.

I wrote my code and for some reason it doesn't return anything, it's completely empty, my ide says I have no errors

```
word = input()
new_word = ''
for char in word:
    if char.isupper():
        new_word.join('_' + char.lower())
    else:
        new_word.join(char)
print(new_word)
```

The assignment runs multiple tests with different words, and here they are

> Sample Input 1:

> python

> Sample Output 1:

> python

> Sample Input 2:

> parselTongue

> Sample Output 2:

> parsel_tongue

I legitimately don't see any reason why it's not printing, any ideas why

Comment: The ‘join()’ method doesn’t do what you think it does. First it returns a new string and second it has no effect on ‘new_word’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the 1st test case is all lower case.
new_word will be empty because loop's inner condition won't execute at all.
Here's the correct and cleaner code I wrote

```
word = input()
counter = 0
new_word = ""

for char in word:
    if not(char.islower()) and counter > 0:
        new_word = new_word + '_' + char.lower()
    else:
        new_word = new_word + char.lower()
    counter += 1
    
print(new_word)
```

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: If the input always starts with a lower case (lowerCamelCase), you can even get rid of the counter.

Comment: Let me test, :)

Comment: `not char.islower()` is basically the same as `char.isupper()`.

Comment: @fsimonjeyz, *not ```char.islower()``` is basically the same as ```char.isupper()```* no. ```isupper()``` and ```islower()``` checks if the whole string is upper case or lowercase respectively

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You have to concatenate the characters to `new_word` and not `join`.

This is Concatenation. `char` gets appended to `new_word`:

> `new_word += char`

`join()` will just concatenate and return the strings passed to it. But it is not saved to `new_word`.

Use concatenation instead of `join` in your code.

```
word = input('Input: ')
new_word = ''
for char in word:
    if char.isupper():
        new_word += '_' + char.lower()
    else:
        new_word += char
print(f'Output: {new_word}')
```

```
Input: python
Output: python

Input: parselTongue
Output: parsel_tongue
```

Answer (score 0):

As your title says "list comprehension", here is an approach that utilizes a comprehension:

```py
snake_word = ''.join(f'_{c.lower()}' if c.isupper() else c for c in word)
```